# python statement: (k,v) for k,v

Tags: python-2.7

I use pycharm with python 2.7

For a dictionary param, I try to use the following two statements:

```
   *print "%s=%s" %(k,v) for k,v in param.items()
    print ["%s=%s" %(k,v) for k,v in param.items()]*
```

The first line has a syntax error because the k,v can't be resolved, but the second line could be executed normally. How should I understand that, and how can the IDE find k,v for the second line?

I know the second line belongs to list comprehension, but it makes me confused because parts of a valid statement is invalid, so this kind of statement can be used only within a list?

Answer (score 0):

The first line has a syntax error because it's invalid syntax. The second line is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: I know it is list comprehension,but it is quite strange. parts of a valid statement is invalid

Comment: Of course it is. It isn't valid unless you have the whole thing.